# How to implement CloudKit Undo/Redo

Tags: cloudkit

I was just wondering if anyone has a better idea how to implement undo/redo for the CloudKit transactions or if they see some obvious flaws in mine.

I made a Mac app in which I use CoreData as the local store and CloudKit. When CloudKit is not in use, I use CoreData's UndoManager for undo/redo and that works fine.

For CloudKit undo I listen for NSUndoManagerDidUndoChangeNotification, sent by the local UndoManager, and when I receive it, I send the opposite operation to the iCloud. So if the original was Add, I will send Delete for undo, if it was Delete, send Add and if it was Update, Update with previous version of data.

Similarly for redo. I listen for NSUndoManagerDidRedoChangeNotification and send appropriate transaction to cloud.

For each transaction that uses CloudKit, I call moc!.undoManager!.beginUndoGrouping() at the beginning of the local transaction and moc!.undoManager!.endUndoGrouping() when I receive completion of the same transaction from the iCloud.

However, often I get a situation when this seems to fall apart. Somehow, begin and end groupings fall out of sync. I tried to only include important changes for undo/redo with moc!.undoManager!.disableUndoRegistration() and moc!.undoManager!.enableUndoRegistration() but I still get errors, mainly "endUndoGrouping called with no matching begin"

So, it would be great if anyone has a comment on this.

Comment: Databases use transaction logs, which they replay and copy to each other. You need to perhaps create a transaction log and do your changes relative to that.